# What are min / max value of floats and doubles?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I already googled and checked limits.h with no results.

I'm hoping there are constants I can refer to hiding somewhere.

Answer (score 10):

You can use FLT_MIN, FLT_MAX:

```
NSLog(@"MIN=%f;MAX=%f", FLT_MIN, FLT_MAX);

Output:
MIN=0.000000;MAX=340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000
```

Comment: Here FLT_MIN value describes the minimun negative magnitude value, the real minimum value is -FLT_MAX

Answer (score 4):

You can use `FLT_MIN` and `FLT_MAX` for Float value and `DBL_MIN` and `DBL_MAX` for Double value to find minimum magnitude value.

Keep in mind that it is minimum magnitude value, The minimum numeric value for float is `-FLT_MAX` and for double it is `-DBL_MAX`

Their values are as:

```
FLT_MIN:0.000000(magnitude value, in real minimum float value= -FLT_MAX)

FLT_MAX:340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000

DBL_MIN:0.000000(magnitude value, in real minimum float value= -DBL_MAX)

DBL_MAX:179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368.000000
```